# Rails: How do I cancel a save if before_update callback returns false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which has a `before_update` callback. From my understanding `before_update` is called when `update_attributes` is called on a model instance. My assumption is that if the `before_update` callback returns `false` the record will not be updated.

This doesn't seem to work as assumed, however. Every time I call `update_attributes`, the record gets saved even if `before_update` returns `false`. Do you have any idea how to prevent the record from being updated if `before_update` returns `false`? Here's what I've tried in my user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :first_name, :last_name,  :presence => true

  before_update do
    false
  end

end
```

Here's what I've tried in rails console:

```
u = User.new(:first_name=>"John", :last_name => "Doe")
=> #<User id: nil, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

u.update_attributes(:first_name=>nil)
=> false 

u.changed?
=> true 

u
=> #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: "Doe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the Ruby object has changed. Check to see if the corresponding database row has changed - it shouldn't have.

Rails validation doesn't prevent object properties from changing, it prevents them being saved to the database.

Comment: How do I check if the corresponding database row has changed within rails?

Comment: Also how do I prevent the object from being changed, if before_update returns false?

Comment: update_attributes returned false so it didn't changed :) For the second one I don't think there is a way, but you can reload your object when update failed